# SQL for highest sold Products

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Order Sample data:

```
ORDER_DAY   ORDER_ID  PRODUCT_ID QUANTITY   PRICE
---------- --------- ----------- ---------- --------- 
01-JUL-11  O1        P1          5               5
01-JUL-11  O2        P2          2              10
01-JUL-11  O3        P3          10             25
01-JUL-11  O4        P1          20             5
02-JUL-11  O5        P3          5              25
02-JUL-11  O6        P4          6              20
02-JUL-11  O7        P1          2              5
02-JUL-11  O8        P5          1              50
02-JUL-11  O9        P6          2              50
02-JUL-11  O10       P2          4              10
```

Q: Get me highest sold Products (Qty* Price) on both days

Desired output :

```
DATE      PRODUCT_ID SOLD_AMOUNT
01-JUL-11      P3        250
02-JUL-11      P3        125
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, you seem new here.
It's generally considered good form to have a go at the problem yourself, and show us what you tried, before asking for help. Have you tried googling for anything yet? What did you find and why didn't it help you?

Answer (score 1):

Try following query:

```
select order_day, product_id, totalsale
from (select order_day,
           product_id,
           nvl(QUANTITY, 0) * PRICE as totalsale,
           dense_rank() over(partition by ORDER_DAY order by(nvl(QUANTITY, 0) * PRICE) desc) as maxsum
      from orders )
where maxsum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would start with getting the sold amount per day and product. With this data you first select the maximum profit per day and then select those entries that match this:

```
WITH PRODUCT_PER_DAY AS
(
  SELECT ORDER_DAY, PRODUCT_ID, SUM(QUANTITY * PRICE) AS SOLD_AMOUNT
  FROM MYTABLE 
  GROUP BY ORDER_DAY, PRODUCT_ID
)
SELECT ORDER_DAY, PRODUCT_ID, SOLD_AMOUNT
FROM PRODUCT_PER_DAY
WHERE (ORDER_DAY, SOLD_AMOUNT) IN
(
  SELECT ORDER_DAY, MAX(SOLD_AMOUNT)
  FROM PRODUCT_PER_DAY 
  GROUP BY ORDER_DAY
)
ORDER BY ORDER_DAY, PRODUCT_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select b.product_id,a.order_day,a.total_price from(select order_day, max(quantity*price)as total_price from order group by order_day)a 
join (select product_id , quantity * price as total_amount from order)b on 
a.total_price= b.total_price
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out (modify the table and column names as per your needs):

```
    Select a.order_day, b.product_id, a.sales 
    from  
          (select order_day, max(quantity*price) as sales
           from ordr
           group by order_day) a
    inner join
         (select order_day, product_id, quantity*price as sales
          from ordr) b
    on a.order_day = b.order_day and a.sales = b.sales;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with temp as 
(select order_day,product_id,sum(quantity*price) qp
  from orders_amazn
  group by order_day,product_id
)
select * from (select order_day,product_id,qp,
      dense_rank() over (partition by order_day order by qp desc) rnk
from temp)
where rnk=1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    select t.ORDER_DAY as date1 ,t.PRODUCT_ID,max(t.quantity * t.price) 
as sold_amount from table t group by t.ORDER_DAY,t.PRODUCT_ID
```

Comment: No. You are not even using group by. How is this supposed to work then?

Comment: Okay, this is syntactically fine now. However, you select the maximum profit per day and product rather than the maximum profit per day :-) The query needed is actually not that simple, as you can see from my own answer.

Answer (score -1):

select date,product_id,max(product_id*price) as sold_amount form order
group by order_day
order by order_day

Comment: No. You group by order_day. So which product_id do you want to be shown?

Answer (score -2):

Kindly use this query you will be the desired output.I have tried in MySQL.

```
SELECT
order_date,
Product_id,
sold_amount
FROM
(
    SELECT
        date_format(order_day,'%d-%b-%y') AS order_date,
        Product_id,
        SUM(price*quantity) AS sold_amount
    FROM
        ecommerce
    GROUP BY
        date_format(order_day,'%d-%b-%y'),
        product_id) a
WHERE
(
    order_date,sold_amount) IN
(
    SELECT
        DATE,
        MAX(sold_amt) AS sold_amount
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                date_format(order_day,'%d-%b-%y') AS DATE,
                product_id,
                SUM(price*quantity) AS sold_amt
            FROM
                ecommerce
            GROUP BY
                date_format(order_day,'%d-%b-%y'),
                product_id)a
    GROUP BY
        DATE)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
select order_day as orderdate,product_id,max(quantity * price) as sold_amount
from order
group by order_day
order by product_id
```

Comment: Well, not sure why the downvote but the grouping is wrong for sure.

Comment: sum(quantity*price) not product_id

Comment: @RishabhRaj I removed my downvote, but the group by is still wrong.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov i saw the column name date in the result so i used it in the query.i corrected it to the order_day.i think its right now.

Comment: @RishabhRaj Hey buddy, I suggest you try this query somewhere, just run it.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov i just executed the above query in phpmyadmin's mysql and its working perfectly.

Comment: This is Oracle. You can't mess with the group by that way. It will result in a `ORA-00979` syntactical error. Apart from that, even in MySQL the grouping will be wrong because you're not choosing a product_id to fetch.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov please correct the column names because in your table all column names are capital but in my query all are small.

Comment: @MostyMostacho in the problem it is clearly mentioned that he want the max sold according to the day and hence i am grouping by order_day

Comment: @RishabhRaj This makes no difference, but OK -> here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a944d/22

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov i cant find out y it is not working in fiddle as i executed in my mysql.if u know any error in my sql syntax u r welcome to point out.

Comment: @RishabhRaj Well you need to include the `product_id` in the `group by`

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov why we need to include product_id ?

Comment: @RishabhRaj Also, the column can't be named `DATE`

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov +1 for date part,thats silly mistake from my part(i corrected it) but still i dont think in this question context we should use product_id in group by clause.

Comment: This does not work in Oracle DBMS (or standard sql for that matter). Either select product_id and have this in your group by clause or select an aggregate of product_id.

Comment: Yes MySQL doesn't confirm to the standard here. This doesn't work in other dbms. However, MySQL freely chooses one product_id within the group (the order_day). This isn't necessarily the one with maximum profit. As there is more than one product_id per order_day, you would have to explicitely tell the dbms which product_id to show. Here is a link elaborating the MySQL group by extension: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html